# How to build packaged pom as jar

Tags: java, maven

I've got maven project which contains 4 modules and "root". I've compiled all of modules but I have got a problem with main project. I must compile it as jar but it's not possible because error log tells me it must have be packaged as pom. It's possible to compile it as jar?

```
Here is my poms:
fabe-core (root): https://hastebin.com/goyuduvifu.xml
fabe-rp: https://hastebin.com/folezuhuqe.xml
fabe-api: https://hastebin.com/oveyucuvoj.xml
fabe-brooms: https://hastebin.com/umimojoley.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you are trying to set up a Multi-Module project and want to do the main module and the parent pom in one pom file, as far as I know this is not possible.

I would suggest you read the instructions to a multi module project which is documented here https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html and adjust your project accordingly.